# Eclipse - "Keep JUnit running after a test when debugging"

Tags: eclipse, debugging, selenium, junit, run-configuration

In Eclipse there is an option under Run/Debug configuration *Keep JUnit running after a test when debugging*.

Googling for that phrase only returns one hit, a bug report at Eclipse (61174), that is no manual, instruction or similar. Hence I have two questions:

1. What does this option affect?
2. The reason I found this option was that I was looking for a way to make running a test faster. Currently it takes 35 seconds for JUnit to start while running the actual tests usually just takes a few seconds. This is very annoying when I debug test cases and need to start/stop them frequently. Is there a way to make JUnit launch faster?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I've ran into this myself:

A JUnit launch configuration has a "keep alive" option. If your Java virtual machine supports "hot code replacement" you can fix the code and rerun the test without restarting the full test run. To enable this option select the Keep JUnit running after a test run when debugging checkbox in the JUnit launch configuration.

From the site: http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-junit.htm

Comment: Hi @Christain Weaves ,@d-b, I tried this by checking checkbox in tomcat and after that once test completed I want to rerun it but could not find way to run it, if I goes by right click --> Debug JUnit again then I do all process again. Can you suggest way for it .